# Oracle: Numbered groups in a hierarchical query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

In my Oracle DB, I have a table deifining a hierarchy of predecessors/successors, which can both branch and loop. I have attached an SQL fiddle to demonstrate how the table works. My intention is to assign each isolated tree it's own number. See picture below for explanation of the desired result (please note that in this picture the members are named **a,b,c,d**... whereas in the fiddle attached, they are numbered **1,2,3,4**...):

[image: Desired output in diagram form] [image: Desired output in table form]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c887d/4/0

I haven't yet figured out how to build such a query and at this very moment I'm pretty much desperate.
Any help, or even a pointer to the solution - any kind of input - will be appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I am unable to understand how you want your result output from the fiddle link. Could you add your expected result

Comment: Hi @Sujitmohanty30, the fiddle isn't exactly supposed to **explain** the desired output. The diagram is included with the question for that exact reason. However, I have added a second picture to demonstrate my desired output in a table form, which will be much easier to understand. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't hierarchies; they are directed graphs.  You can still use `CONNECT BY` in Oracle to work with them, but without a root node to `START WITH`, performance might be a problem if your data set is large.

Anyway, what you need to do is `CONNECT BY NOCYCLE` without a `START WITH`.  That will compute a tree starting from each separate node.  Then, get the `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` for each node and take the `MIN()` for each distinct node value.

Here is a working example, with data.  It's more complicated than it needs to be because there is nowhere to get a complete list of all the nodes, so you have to split each vertex into two rows (one have the from_node and one have the to_node) to make sure you're including all of them.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_tst ( from_node VARCHAR2(1), to_node VARCHAR2(1) );

INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'a', 'b');
INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'b', 'd');
INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'd', 'a');
INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'd', 'e');

INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'f', 'g');
INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'g', 'h');
INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'h', 'f');

INSERT INTO tbl_tst VALUES ( 'i', 'j');

COMMIT;


WITH groups AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
       tt.from_node, 
       tt.to_node, 
       MIN(CONNECT_BY_ROOT(from_node)) 
             OVER ( PARTITION BY tt.from_node) group_min
FROM   tbl_tst tt
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE from_node = PRIOR to_node
              OR   to_node = PRIOR from_node
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY group_min ) group_number,
       DECODE(splitter.rn,1,groups.from_node,2,groups.to_node) node       
FROM groups 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT rownum rn FROM dual CONNECT BY rownum <= 2 ) splitter
GROUP BY DECODE(splitter.rn,1,groups.from_node,2,groups.to_node),
         group_min
ORDER BY group_min, node;
```

> ```
> +--------------+------+
> | GROUP_NUMBER | NODE |
> +--------------+------+
> |            1 | a    |
> |            1 | b    |
> |            1 | c    |
> |            1 | d    |
> |            1 | e    |
> |            2 | f    |
> |            2 | g    |
> |            2 | h    |
> |            3 | i    |
> |            3 | j    |
> +--------------+------+
> ```

Comment: `from_node = PRIOR to_node` -- maybe change to `from_node = PRIOR to_node OR to_node = PRIOR from_node`, since you don't need to consider the direction of the arcs of the graph. This change can walk the subgraphs faster, producing less branches, and improving performance. Well... as long as I understood your solution well.

Comment: @TheImpaler That actually produces more rows in that first CTE.  Making the `CONNECT BY` condition broader makes more connections, not fewer.

Comment: @TheImpaler but I just realized that my solution doesn't work if you had a row, say, "m->h".  So, I think I need your change to product correct results in all cases.  Thank you.

Comment: You solution is far more concise than mine. Plus, it works in Oracle. +1

Comment: Holy smokes. This works perfectly. I'll take some time to analyze your solution and the specific inner workings, but the bounty is yours for sure.1 hour until I'm able to award it. Hats off - and also, thanks for giving me a pointer to find more about this problem. Knowing how it's called will help me dive deeper into it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood in other words, for each root_node you need a group number assigned to it. To find the root node we can use `connect_by_root` and then we can use dense_rank to give it a number.

So far I got this, could you check [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c887d/12)

```
SELECT predecessor
      ,successor
      ,sys_connect_by_path(successor
                          ,'/') AS hierarchy_path
      ,LEVEL node_level
      ,dense_rank() over(ORDER BY connect_by_root successor) group_number
FROM   tbl_tst
CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR predecessor = successor;
```

Comment: Not exactly, although this is getting close. GROUP_NUMBERs 1,2,3 as presented in your fiddle, should be all GROUP_NUMBER=1, since there are connections between them. Path /1/3/2 is a part of the same tree as path /2/1/3 or /3/2/1. Therefore, they should all have the same GROUP_NUMBER.

Comment: Understood your point. Need some analysis here. Tried with some changes but no luck

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: This solution works in PostgreSQL, not in Oracle as requested.**

The query below demonstrates a strategy to solve the problem of assigning unique serial numbers to each subgraph.

**Note:** I tried to write the query for Oracle but it seems the XMLTable() function is buggy. Maybe you can adapt it to Oracle if you find a workaround (I gave up).

```
with recursive
n (root_id, pred, succ, s) as (
  select pred, pred, succ, '/' || least(pred, succ) || '/' || greatest(pred, succ) || '/' from t
 union all
  select n.root_id, t.pred, t.succ, (
    select '/' || string_agg(vl, '/') || '/' from (
      select unnest(string_to_array(substring(n.s from 2 for length(n.s) - 2), '/')) as vl
      union all select (case when t.pred = n.pred or t.pred = n.succ then t.succ else t.pred end)
      order by vl
      ) y
    )
  from n
  join t on not (n.pred = t.pred and n.succ = t.succ) and (n.pred = t.pred or n.pred = t.succ or n.succ = t.pred or n.succ = t.succ)
            and not n.s ~ ('/' || case when t.pred = n.pred or t.pred = n.succ then t.succ else t.pred end || '/')
),
s as (
  select distinct s from (
    select distinct on (root_id) root_id, s from n group by root_id, s order by root_id, length(s) desc
  ) j
)
select * from (
  select
    unnest(string_to_array(substring(s from 2 for length(s) - 2), '/')) as node,
    row_number() over(order by s) as g 
  from s order by s
) z
order by g, node;
```

Result:

```
node  g
----  -
a     1
b     1
c     1
d     1
e     1
f     2
g     2
h     2
i     3
j     3
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnmqs5whgVMUSesRipTzMN/0).